# How can I extract confidence intervals for all non-reference leveled contiuous variable coefficients from one lmer model?

Tags: r, lme4, confidence-interval

I'm fitting a `y ~ v + m + s + m:s + (1|subunit)` model with lmer().  `s` is a continuous variable interacting with `m`, a categorical factor with 3 levels: **A**, **B**, and **C**.

Fitting the model uses **A** as the reference level for factor `m`:

`fit_ref_A <- lmer(y ~ 1 + v + m*s + (1|subunit), data=df)`

The parameter estimates for **B** and **C** can just be calculated using the estimate for **A** and the differences for **B** and **C**.  I'm interested in extracting the confidence intervals.

Running confint() gives the confidence interval for the slope of variable `s` at **A**.  I'm also interested in the confidence intervals of the slopes of `s` at **B** and **C**, not just the confidence intervals for the differences from the slope at **A**.  Is there a way to extract this from `fit_ref_A`?  So far the only thing I've been able to figure out is to relevel with **B** as the reference, fit a new fit, then relevel with **C** as the reference, and fit the third fit.

**Question:  Is there a way to extract everything (especially the confidence intervals) from `fit_ref_A`?**

Code:

```
library(lme4)
# create the dataset, unbalanced at the lowest stratum ( 2 repeats for m==A instead of 3)
set.seed(2)
s_levels <- 1:5
m_levels <- c("A", "B", "C")
v_levels <- c("L2", "L3", "L4")
reps <- 1:3
df <- expand.grid(rep=reps, s=s_levels, m=m_levels, v=v_levels)
df$subunit <- as.factor(paste(df$v,"-",df$m,"-",df$s, sep=""))
df$y <- rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 1)
df <- subset(df, !(rep==3 & m=="A"))  # drop the 3rd repeat for m=="A"
table(df$m)  # shows 30 for A, 45 for B, 45 for C as expected

# fit 3 different models, with three different reference levels for 'm'
fit_ref_A <- lmer(y ~ 1 + v + m*s + (1|subunit), data=df)

df$m <- relevel(df$m, ref = "B")
fit_ref_B <- lmer(y ~ 1 + v + m*s + (1|subunit), data=df)

df$m <- relevel(df$m, ref = "C")
fit_ref_C <- lmer(y ~ 1 + v + m*s + (1|subunit), data=df)

# Calculate the confidence intervals for the continuous variable s at the three
# different levels for categorical factor m.  Must use 3 separate fits.

cis_at_m_reference_A <- confint(fit_ref_A)
cis_at_m_reference_B <- confint(fit_ref_B)
cis_at_m_reference_C <- confint(fit_ref_C)

cis_at_m_reference_A["s",]
cis_at_m_reference_B["s",]
cis_at_m_reference_C["s",]

# Any way to just extract all three from fit_ref_A?
```

Comment: The slope at `B` is the `s` coef + the `(m == B):s` coef, and similarly for the other values. You don't need to relevel and re-fit the model, you can add the coefficients you have.

Comment: @GregorThomas Right. The point estimates are easy.  I'm interested in the confidence limits, which cannot be gotten in the same easy way.  I've edited my question to make it more clear that I want to extract the confidence limits.

Answer (score 2):

You can get approximate CIs with Gaussian error propagation:

```
sum(fixef(fit_ref_A)[c("s", "mB:s")]) + 
  c(-1.96, 1.96) * sqrt(sum(vcov(fit_ref_A)[c("s", "mB:s"), c("s", "mB:s")]))
#[1] -0.3346310  0.1863014
```

Or you could bootstrap:

```
myboot <- bootMer(fit_ref_A, function(x) {
  cf <- fixef(x)
  c(sA = cf[["s"]], sB = cf[["s"]] + cf[["mB:s"]], sC = cf[["s"]] + cf[["mC:s"]])
}, nsim = 1e4, seed = 42)

apply(myboot$t, 2, quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
#              sA         sB         sC
#2.5%  -0.4022927 -0.3415690 -0.3969831
#97.5%  0.2041610  0.1858731  0.1266355
```

Comment: So, is there no way to get the profile confidence intervals from fit_ref_A?

Comment: Well, I'd say no. You can only profile model parameters.

Comment: Ok, so is the following correct?  fit_ref_A and fit_ref_B are the same model and same fit, but because they are different representations of the model with different parameters, and profiling is parameter-dependent, I can't get the profile confidence intervals for **B** from fit_ref_A.  I have to profile the model-representation fit_ref_B?

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I'm going to leave the question open for now to see if someone (or yourself?) either confirms my explanation in the previous comment, or explains why it is incorrect and the actual reason getting profile CIs for **B** from fit_ref_A cannot be done. Thanks.